# command line bash_profile

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have installed ruby rails , but whenever I open the terminal I have to enter the `source ~ / .bash_profile` , command me to accept the `rails command` , there is some way that we no longer do it all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
cat ~/.bash_profile >> ~/.bashrc
```

to make the commands work in all newly opened terminals for your user.

Comment: @CarlosUrielPatiñoSantiago no, that should work without reboot. Probably there was some nontrivial content in `~/.bashrc` before appending. Difficult to tell why it doesn't work witohut full content of `~/.bashrc`. And yes, commands will work only in newly opened terminals.

Comment: ok , thanks, but I did it anyway and have to run the command , something must be going wrong . @Sergey

Answer (score 0):

just echo the command into the `.bashrc` located at the profile of the current user.

```
echo "~/.bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc
```

The file `~/.bashrc` is "sourced" everytime you execute `/bin/bash` command or open a new terminal.

Comment: @CarlosUrielPatiñoSantiago no you don't have to reboot .. just close the current terminal session and open a new one

Comment: ok , I get if I work, but still I have to keep writing / bin / bash always , thanks anyway ! @CMPS

Comment: What distro are you using ?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS, gnome 3.20.3 @CMPS

Answer (score 0):

Try putting whatever path configuration you need into .bashrc instead of .bash_profile.  .bash_profile is sourced automatically only in a "login shell".  See further https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc